# Accessing data in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, relation

I'm new to the Yii2 framework and I'm now trying to acces data in Listview using relations. Can somebody please explain why my code isn't working.
I want to find a tag which belongs to a document.

Here is a screenshot of my database:
[image]

Here is my relation:

```
public function getTags() {
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
                    ->viaTable('tbl_document_tag', ['document_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    public function actionTag() {
     $model = new Search();
     $tag = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('tag');

    //Documents
    $documentModel = new Document;
    $documentSearch = $model->searchDocumentsByTag($documentModel, $tag);

    return $this->render('results', [
        'model' => $model,
        'documentSearch' => $documentSearch,
        'documentModel' => $documentModel
    ]);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
    public function searchDocumentsByTag($documentsModel, $keyword) {
    $query = Document::find()
            ->with('tags')
            ->andFilterWhere([
        'or',
        ['like', 'tags.state', 1],
        ['like', 'tags.slug', $keyword],
    ]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    return $dataProvider;
```

I get the following error:

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags.state' in 'where clause'
>   The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_document` WHERE (`tags`.`state` LIKE '%1%') OR (`tags`.`slug` LIKE '%steekwoord%')
>   Error Info: Array
>   (
>       [0] => 42S22
>       [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GO08.png) => 1054
>       [2] => Unknown column 'tags.state' in 'where clause'
>   )
>   ↵
>   Caused by: PDOException
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags.state' in 'where clause'

Comment: How is your code not working? What errors are you receiving? You need to describe what outcome you are trying to achieve

Comment: try this one like `['like', 'tbl_tag.state', 1],['like', 'tbl_tag.slug', $keyword]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use [`joinWith()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail) instead of [`with()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail) :

> This method allows you to reuse existing relation definitions to perform JOIN queries. [...] Note that because a JOIN query will be performed, you are responsible to disambiguate column names.

e.g. :

```
$query = Document::find()
    ->joinWith('tags tags')
    ->andFilterWhere([
        'or',
        ['like', 'tags.state', 1],
        ['like', 'tags.slug', $keyword],
    ]);
```